# How to get coordinates from postal codes and add them into df using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, coordinates

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'Postcode': ['M3A','M4A','M5A','M6A','M9A','M1B'], 'Borough': ['North York', 'Downtown Toronto', 'Etobicoke', 
                                                                    'Scarborough', 'East York', 'York'], 
     'Neighbourhood': ['Parkwoods', 'Victoria Village', 'Harbourfront', 'Regent Park',
       'Lawrence Heights', 'Lawrence Manor']}
post_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Which yields something like:

```
    Postcode    Borough             Neighbourhood
0   M3A         North York          Parkwoods
1   M4A         Downtown Toronto    Victoria Village
2   M5A         Etobicoke           Harbourfront
3   M6A         Scarborough         Regent Park
4   M9A         East York           Lawrence Heights
5   M1B         York                Lawrence Manor
```

I want to get all the latitudes and longitudes for each postal code.
I figured out this code to do so:

```
import geocoder

# initialize your variable to None
lat_lng_coords = None

# loop until you get the coordinates
while(lat_lng_coords is None):
  g = geocoder.google('{}, Toronto, Ontario'.format(postal_code_from_df))
  lat_lng_coords = g.latlng

latitude = lat_lng_coords[0]
longitude = lat_lng_coords[1]
```

now my question is: Using the previous code, I would like to get each latitude and longitude for each postal code and add them to 2 new columns in this existing df called 'Latitude' and 'Longitude'. How could I do that using a single loop to avoid searching each postal code coordinates one by one?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply`. Something like:

```
post_df['Latitude'], post_df['Longitude'] = zip(*post_df['Postcode'].apply(get_geocoder))
```

Where `get_geocoder` can be defined as mentioned by @Ankur

Comment: Thank you!! This does exactly what i was looking for!! It helped

Comment: Hi panktijk.Would have an idea of how to refactor this code to be more time efficient? It's been running since almost 25 minutes by now and it's not finished yet. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: How big is your dataframe?

Comment: 211 rows and 3 columns. It's not huge but the problem is that since the geocoder package does not always get the coordinates at the first call, i need that while loop to be sure i'm getting all of the coordinates. I'm not sure if the while loop could be the problem. But your line the function and the code you provided still running, it's getting too much long

Comment: You can check how much time your `while` loop is taking to execute for each row. If the `apply` is taking more time, then you can use `np.vectorize` instead, which is much more time efficient than `dfp.apply`.

Comment: thanks i'm gonna try that. Would it be something like this:

`df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'] = np.vectorize(get_geocoder(zip(*df['Postcode'])))`??

Comment: You don't actually need to explicity use `np.vectorize`. You can just do something like: `df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'] = get_geocoder(df['Postcode'].values)`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to define your geocoder function and loop it on your df. I am passing your Postal code column one by one in the function and to fetch values from geocoder and assigning and storing it into two new columns latitude and longitude. See below:

```
  import geocoder



def get_geocoder(postal_code_from_df):
     # initialize your variable to None
     lat_lng_coords = None
     # loop until you get the coordinates
     while(lat_lng_coords is None):
       g = geocoder.google('{}, Toronto, Ontario'.format(postal_code_from_df))
       lat_lng_coords = g.latlng
     latitude = lat_lng_coords[0]
     longitude = lat_lng_coords[1]
     return latitude,longitude



for i in range(0,len(post_df)):
    post_df['Latitude'][i],post_df['Longitude'][i]=get_geocoder(post_df.iloc[i]['Postcode'])
```

This should work for you.

Comment: If it helps, Please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Ankur. Thank you for your answer. But it don't work. i'm getting the following error:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c85e0b79421e> in <module>()
     15 
     16 
---> 17 for i in range(0,range(post_df)):
     18    post_df.iloc[i]['Latitude'],post_df.iloc[i]['Longitude']=get_geocoder(post_df.iloc[i]['Postcode'])

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: i fixed the conflictive line of your code:

`for i in range(0,(len(post_df['Postcode']))):
    post_df.iloc[i]['Latitude'],post_df.iloc[i]['Longitude']=get_geocoder(post_df.iloc[i]['Postcode'])`

Although, this is not creating the 2 new columns with the latitudes and longitudes and adding the data to them. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @Miguel2488 This should work: 
for i in range(0,len(post_df)):
    post_df['Latitude'][i],post_df['Longitude'][i]=get_geocoder(post_df.iloc[i]['Postcode'])

Comment: Hi ankur, your solution works. But putting my code and your code together into practice it's being really inefficient in terms of time. I asked @panktijk if he had any ideas to refactorize this code to make it more time efficient, and i would like to ask you the same. Please see my answer to panktijk at the top for more details. Thanks again